# ERROR/dalvikvm(1399): Could not find class 'maptest.xyz.com.maps', referenced from method maptest.xyz.com.maptest$1.onClick

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The problem is that if i use these two lines of code,my app closes unxepectedly and if not used, the app works just fine...is there any other way to get to the maps.class? 
The following is the code i used:

```
     Intent in = new Intent(BlobCity.this, maps.class)
       startActivity(in);
```

the following is my manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="BlobCity.xyz.com"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">       
    <activity android:name=".BlobCity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
  <activity android:name=".maps" />
     </application>

      </manifest>
```

blobcity.java:

```
public class BlobCity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button signIn,register;
    TextView Blob,City,username,password;
    EditText eUsername,ePassword;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signIn);  
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        Blob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blob);
        City = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);

        eUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eUsername);
        ePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePassword);

        signIn.setOnClickListener(new sendUserPass());
        register.setOnClickListener(new regPage());
    }

    class sendUserPass implements Button.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String uname = eUsername.getText().toString();
            String pwd = ePassword.getText().toString();
            String requestString = ("http://192.168.1.102:8080/BlobCity/RemoteLogin?email="+ uname + "&pwd=" + pwd);
            String line;

            try {
                HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(requestString));
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder rb = new StringBuilder("");

                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    rb.append(line) ;
                }
                if(rb.toString().equals("0"))
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid Username and/or Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);

                    eUsername.setText("");
                    ePassword.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent in = new Intent(BlobCity.this, maps.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    eUsername.setText("");
                    ePassword.setText("");   
                }
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class regPage implements Button.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent browse = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://www.blobcity.com") );
            startActivity(browse);
        }
    }
}
```

maps.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class maps extends MapActivity{
    MapView mapView; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your log say? Any errors?

Comment: no...the app just stops and forces a close when using this piece of code

Comment: ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=BlobCity.xyz.com/.BlobCity }

Comment: well, not able to judge anything from this log.................. It might be telling some errors or giving stack,   check it there.........      for some clues.......

Comment: 11-15 21:59:28.827: ERROR/dalvikvm(1399): Could not find class 'maptest.xyz.com.maps', referenced from method maptest.xyz.com.maptest$1.onClick

Answer (score 1):

Your tag `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` has to be **inside the `<application>` tag!**

manifest has to be like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="BlobCity.xyz.com"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">       
  **<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />** 
    <activity android:name=".BlobCity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
  <activity android:name=".maps" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Intent in = new Intent(BlobCity.this.getApplicationContext(), maps.class)
startActivity(in);
```

Comment: 11-15 21:59:28.827: ERROR/dalvikvm(1399): Could not find class 'maptest.xyz.com.maps', referenced from method maptest.xyz.com.maptest$1.onClick

Answer (score 0):

`Activity (Class)` name must start with capital letter,  and instead of using `BlobCity.this` use only "this" keyword which refers the `Context` of the current `Activity`

e.g.

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, Maps.class)
startActivity(in);
```

also make sure entry of this `Activity` must be in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

e.g.

```
 <activity android:name=".Maps"></activity>
```

also you can follow a great tutorial on Android Google Maps here :

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: i have done whatever you have mentioned above...but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: If possible, post your whole code snippet or just post the error log from eclipse LogCat view

Comment: I'm not getting what exactly occurring. If you can post the complete log from the LogCat view not from Console view (as you had posted in previous comment). You can view compelete log as follows: Go to : "Window >>>>  Show View >>>> Other >>> Android >>>> LogCat"  then Ok. From there you might get the error log..

Comment: 11-15 21:59:28.827: ERROR/dalvikvm(1399): Could not find class 'maptest.xyz.com.maps', referenced from method maptest.xyz.com.maptest$1.onClick

Comment: If you are unable to post complete error log in comment section, then post it in your question by just editing once again. Until you wont post the full error log no one can judge that what actually happening.